# How to include reference to original function when doing an override with jQuery.extend()

Tags: javascript, debugging, syntax, scope, extend

So, I'm trying to override a function but include it's original methods with the [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method.

```
    var origFunction = $.fn.pluginFunction;
    $.fn.extend({
        pluginFunction: function() {
               // `origFunction` is available via Closure, 
               // now how can I declare the $.extended function here
               // to preserve the original methods and then override
               // only the following object?

                   myObject = {
                        'key1' : 'val1',
                        'key2' : 'val2',
                   }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the original.

```
origFunction.apply(this,arguments);
```

but if `myObject` is a local variable inside of `origFunction`, it is not going to make a difference.

Comment: This doesn't work because executing `origFunction.apply(this,arguments)` executes the function prematurely .  I'm trying to debug it, and add a callback so that I can ensure the function is properly extended before executing it but the `origFunction()` apply that you suggested is actually the source of my problem - walking through it in debugger, it is at this line where the plugin executes prior to being extended.

Comment: How does it execute it prematurely? Not getting what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Modified code: call `origFunction` using  `apply`. You change myObject only if it is not a private variable of method(it should be global  accessible from overriding method).

```
var origFunction = $.fn.pluginFunction;
    $.fn.extend({
        pluginFunction: function() {
               origFunction.apply(this, arguments); // 
               // `origFunction` is available via Closure, 
               // now how can I declare the $.extended function here
               // to preserve the original methods and then override
               // only the following object?

                   myObject = {
                        'key1' : 'val1',
                        'key2' : 'val2',
                   }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work because executing `origFunction.apply(this,arguments)` executes the function prematurely .  I'm trying to debug it, and add a callback so that I can ensure the function is properly extended before executing it but the `origFunction()` apply that you suggested is actually the source of my problem - walking through it in debugger, it is at this line where the plugin executes prior to being extended.

Answer (score 0):

User apply()

apply calls a function with a set of arguments. It's not part of jQuery, it's part of core Javascript. However, there is mention of it in the jQuery docs:

http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Context.2C_Call_and_Apply

Syntax:

```
somefunction.apply(thisobj, argsarray)
```

The above calls the function somefunction, setting this to thisobj within the function's scope, and passing in the arguments from argsarray as the arguments to the function.